# <select> in Symfony2 Forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two tables,

```
user
-------------------
id | name | city_id
-------------------
1  | abc  | 1
2  | xyz  | 3
3  | hkj  | 3
-------------------
```

and

```
city
---------
id | name
---------
1  | BN
2  | KR
3  | OP
4  | HD
```

I am creating a form using Symfony2 forms. I want to know how to list out all the cities as the `<option>` for a `<select>` form element so that for user `xyz` the following markup is generated.

```
<select>
  <option>BN</option>
  <option>KR</option>
  <option selected='selected'>OP</option>
  <option>HD</option>
</select>
```

I have the code something like this at the moment in my controller,

```
$user = // object of user entity

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
     ->add('name', 'text')
     ->add('city', ...)  // What do I put in here so that I generate the markup as specified above
     ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the 'property' field.

```
->add('city', 'entity', 
         array('required'   => true,
               'label'      => 'label',
               'class'      => 'YourBundle:TheClass',
               'property'   => 'name'
))
```

Sandeepraju's answer applies if you want a query builder to restrict to only some of the choices.

Read more: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property

Answer (score 1):

You can look there: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html
to code something like that:

```
 ->add('city', 'entity', 
          array('required'   => true,
                'label'      => 'label',
                'class'    => 'YourBundle:TheClass',
                'query_builder' => function(YourClassRepository $er) {
                       return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC');
                }
 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

if city is an entity, than it can be simple ->add('city'). If you want a default value, you could provide entity in $options like 'data' => $defaultEntity. Also your city entity must have a __toString method.
However, if you don't have an entity on city, you could use something similar

```
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'),
    'required'  => false,
));
```

> This field may be rendered as one of several different HTML fields, depending on the expanded and multiple options:
>
> - element type-(expanded/multiple)
> - select tag-(false/false)
> - select tag multiple-(false/true)
> - radio buttons-(true/false)
> - checkboxes-(true/true)